# Openai Azure Chat Completion

Tags: python, azure, azure-openai

The following is the code to connect openai via azure in openai>1.0

```
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2023-05-15"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "..."
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "..."

# Import Azure OpenAI
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI

# Create an instance of Azure OpenAI
# Replace the deployment name with your own
llm = AzureOpenAI(
    deployment_name="td2",
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
)

# Run the LLM
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

However, I want to call the llm mode in openai<1.0, say openai==0.28.1.
The above code is not working in openai==0.28.1. How can I access the API in openai<1.0 ?

I want to call the model like that:

```
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

I want to access openai in openai==0.28.1

Comment: Why would you like to use an old version?

Answer (score 0):

Install openai 0.28.1 if you haven't

`pip install openai==0.28.1`

then use this instead

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create( engine="gpt-35-turbo",
                    messages=[
                                {"role": "system", "content": "Assistant is a large language model trained by OpenAI."},
                                {"role": "user", "content": "Who were the founders of Microsoft?"}
                             ])
```

More can be seen in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/chatgpt?tabs=python&pivots=programming-language-chat-completions#working-with-the-gpt-35-turbo-and-gpt-4-models)